# vue.js router active link with url query

Tags: vue.js

When i visit /about everything works good and the about link is active.

When i visit /about?lang=en the about component is rendered as supposed to , but the problem is, the about link is never active.

how can i make the router link active when there's a query?

Note: I've also used  :to="{name:'about'} and it is just the same.

App.vue

```
<template>
 <div id="app">
  <router-link to="/about">About</router-link>
 </div>
</template>
```

router.js

```
routes: [
 {  path: '/about',
   name: 'about',
   component: () => import('./views/About.vue')
 }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

You are probably using `router-link-exact-active` to highlight the current active link. But `/about` and `/about?lang=en` are not an exact match so the class is not active.

You could use `router-link-active`, but this comes with other issues. `router-link-active` is enabled on `/about` even if `/about/path` is accessed. This may not be desired in your use case.

Comment: Is there a way to get the desired behavior? That is, something that matches the path exactly, but ignores query (and hash)?